# C++ logical comparison issue using "!"

Tags: c++, stack, operators

I just completed a homework assignment and I was running into a "bug"(probably just me being stupid); I had a while loop that I wanted to break when two stacks were both empty.

This didn't work

```
while(!poles[0].ISEMPTY() && !poles[1].ISEMPTY){
      //iteratively solve towers of hanoi
```

This worked

```
while(poles[0].ISEMPTY()!= true && poles[1].ISEMPTY()!=true){
     //iteratively solve towers of hanoi

}
```

I feel like I'm missing some basic thing about logical operators...I mean ISEMPTY returns a bool, true if the stack is empty.

Comment: What does `ISEMPTY` return?

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @jaredvan You've gotten an answer to this that looks correct, yet you haven't accepted it. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget the parens on the second call of `ISEMPTY` :P

```
while(!poles[0].ISEMPTY() && !poles[1].ISEMPTY()){
```

fixes it.
(You didn't make that mistake in your working example).

Given that the pointer to the function is non-null, it will always evaluate to true.